# I am trying to make seperate edit and delete on my CRM model but could not figure out how to bind those buttons with my field

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make separate edit and delete on my CRM model but could not figure out how to bind those buttons with my field although I have created the API for this in angular I need a bit help.

Thanks in advance

below is a bootstrap code of the edit and delete buttons

```
<div id="delete_department" class="modal custom-modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content modal-md">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Department</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body card-box">
                        <p>Are you sure want to delete this?</p>
                        <div class="m-t-20 text-left">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" >Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div id="edit_department" class="modal custom-modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="edit(list)">×</button>
      <div class="modal-content modal-md">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Department</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
              <form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Department Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                      <input class="form-control" value="IT Management" type="text">
                  </div>
                  <div class="m-t-20 text-center">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" (click)="edit(list)">Save Changes</button>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is code below?

Comment: Update your question instead, Comments section is not suitable for code

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap Javascript plugins? there are many replacers. I think you can use some other libs to do what you want,eg:bootstrap-vue,element-ui,iview etc

Comment: Yes I am using javascript plugins I just want know how I can bind with angular models so I can delete and edit  data

Answer (score 0):

1: declare a property in your component eg: department,which store the current operate department object on edit button clicked

2: bind the property of department to edit dialog template

3: remove  `role="dialog"` from your dialog template(beacuse you need to do something before dialog open,you must open dialog by yourself)

4: in your edit dialog button click function, you set property 'department' value to store current operate department,and append this code `$('#edit_department').modal('show')`